# Bluetooth Audio gateway problem; system slow to crawl after using serial over Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an application that uses a bluetooth connection to a proprietary device. Everything seems to work fine, except after a while my Samsung tablet slows to an absolute crawl and is basically unusable until the next forced reboot.

I'm seeing this message in alogcat:

E/bluetoothaudiogateway.cpp 2582 pollup detected
audio gateway connect notification
wrp_find_wsock: no entry found
blz_wrapper (2582) btl_if_poll: wsock down, return pollhup pol fd 48, ev 1b

Any ideas on what is going on? It seems this "bluetooth audio gateway" has a bug, but what can I do about it? I'm not using bluetooth for media, how can I get rid of this, etc.?

thanks!

Comment: Do yo manage to solve this problem? I am stuck the same way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does everything speed back up if you disable Bluetooth and re-enable it?
2. How long is "a while"?
3. Have you verified that you don't get those messages if your app is not running?
4. Have you tried your app on a different device?
5. Does the Settings...Manage Applications or Battery Use screens help you out any by indicating if any particular process is consuming a lot of memory and/or CPU?

Comment: Killing BT and restarting helps. But then it all start again afterwards. Problem is that in most cases it is not even possible to disable BT because the tablet freezes completely.

Comment: As far as I remember I get those messages whenever BT is enabled but I'll have to re-check.

Comment: Definitely no problem on other devices.

Comment: I'll need to check the Batter Use. But not sure if it will help since I have to restart in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with the BluetoothAudioGateway.cpp error and Pollhup detected messages using my Samsung Galaxy Ace with factory installed FROYO 2.2.

Since I have two exact same devices, I upgraded 2.2 to 2.3.3 on one device using samsung kies when the update came out at the beginning of this month (September 2011), and have not had this problem using 2.3.3. In fact, when I develop on the 2.2 version I have to restart my device 10 to 20 times a day depending on how much testing I do, while the other Galaxy Ace with 2.3.3 runs all day without having to restart it at all no matter how much I run my application on it.

If upgrading to 2.3.3 is not an option for you, here are some things I have found to help prevent having to restart my 2.2 device:

Most importantly, don't scan for devices while listening for connections. If you're using listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord, stop it by calling BluetoothSocket.close() before scanning for devices and vice versa.

Secondly, don't call close on a BluetoothSocket you have already closed. That gets you an instant freeze in my experience.

Thirdly, When running a new build from eclipse via "run", hit the home button on the device, turn off bluetooth and then run your application. If the application is active while running it from eclipse, it will restart when the debugger kills it and if the application calls bluetooth functions it does something to it... I don't know what, but these voodoo steps have helped save me hours of time all together easily wasted on restarting a frozen device.

It seems to me that these issues are related to Samsung devices running Android 2.2 but I can only report my findings for the Galaxy Ace.